# while getting values in the form it returns null value

Tags: java, playframework

while getting values in the form the bindFromRequest().get() it returns only null value.I got all the String type is null and integr as zer0. Here is my code for controller and model packages and how I can resolve this error:

```
enter code here

 In controller:

  public static Result getShow(){
  Register register=Form.form(Register.class).bindFromRequest().get();
  register.save();
  System.out.println(register);
  return ok("@Required annotation kicked in.."+register);
}
 In Models:

 package models;

 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.Table;

  @Entity
  @Table(name="register")
  public class Register {
//private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 private String firstname;

 private String lastname;
 @Id
 private String displayname;

 private String date;

 private String email; 

 private String password;

 private String confirm_password;

 private String gender;

 private int phone_no;

 private String address;

 private int zipcode;


    public String getFirstname() {
return firstname;

    }
   public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
   }

   public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
   }

   public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
   }
   public String getDisplayname() {
    return displayname;
   }
   public void setDisplayname(String displayname) {
    this.displayname = displayname;
   }
   public String getDate() {
    return date;
   }
   public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
   }
   public String getEmail() {
return email;
    }
   public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
     }
   public String getPassword() {
return password;
   }
   public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
   }
  public String getConfirm_password() {
return confirm_password;
   }
public void setConfirm_password(String confirm_password) {
    this.confirm_password = confirm_password;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public int getPhone_no() {
    return phone_no;
}
public void setPhone__no(int phone_no) {
    this.phone_no = phone_no;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public int getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}
public void setZipcode(int zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `bindFromRequest().get()` returns `null`, then the `Form` didn't validate. To debug this, log `Form.form(Register.class).bindFromRequest().errors()`, to see the validation errors in the `Form`. Beyond that no one can tell you what's wrong without seeing the `Register` class, and the data you're trying to bind to it.

You shouldn't be blindly calling `get()` on the `Form` and trying to save it, as this obviously can fail. *At least* check that it `hasErrors()` before trying to save it. And if it does have validation errors, you should be passing that `Form` back to the view to show those errors to the user.

See [Handling Binding Failure](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms) in the docs.